# HTTPS request not posting body of REST request

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, post

I'm trying to `POST` to an API endpoint on my server.  I know my endpoint works because if I use Advanced REST Client, I can hit it and get a JSON response as expected.  The problem seems to be that no data is being sent in the body of my request despite calling `request.write(postData)` which contains a key, value pair.  Without this data being sent in the body, my server returns a 401 error as expected without this information.  Printing out the content of the POST server-side is empty but I'm clueless as to why it's empty.

```
    var postData = querystring.stringify({
        "access_token" : accessToken,
        "id": applianceId
    });

    var serverError = function (e) {
        log("Error", e.message);
        context.fail(generateControlError(requestName, "DEPENDENT_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE", "Unable to connect to server"));
    };

    var callback = function(response) {
        var str = "";

        response.on("data", function(chunk) {
            str += chunk.toString("utf-8");
        });

        response.on("end", function() {
            result = generateResult(CONTROL, requestName.replace("Request", "Confirmation"), messageId);

            context.succeed(result);
        });

        response.on("error", serverError);
    };

var options = {
    hostname: REMOTE_CLOUD_HOSTNAME,
    port: 443,
    path: REMOTE_CLOUD_BASE_PATH + "/" + endpoint,
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    }
};

var request = https.request(options, callback);

request.on("error", serverError);

//This doesn't seem to write anything since if I print out the POST
//data server-side it's empty; however, if I print out the value of
//postData here, it looks as expected: 'access_token=xxxxx'
request.write(postData);

request.end();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have testing you code again `httpbin.org/post` and it seems that it is working.
I believe that the issue related to, that your should POST `application/json` and not "`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Please try to change the header

```
headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
```

Then, try to change the postData to JSON string:

```
var postData=JSON.stringify({access_token:"xxxxx"})
```

To be sure that problem you success to send and the problem is not local (maybe there is an issue in your server), change the target to mirror URL:

```
var options = {
    hostname: "httpbin.org",
    path:'/post',
    port: 443,
    method: "POST",    
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
};
```

If there is no problem in your NodeJS version, the is the response you should get: (It is mean that the server got the posted data)

```
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "{\"access_token\":\"xxxxx\"}", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Content-Length": "24", 
    "Content-Type": "application/json", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org"
  }, 
  "json": {
    "access_token": "xxxxx"
  }, 
  "origin": "5.29.63.30", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

BTW: I really recommend you to move to a library to manage the request for you:

- https://github.com/request/request - Very popular
- https://github.com/request/request-promise - For popular who like to use the Promise syntax (The next thing in JavaScript)
- https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent - For people who like to write same code in Browser & Server

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately the problem won't be solved by switching to JSON, since I have it working with the current content type in ARC. It's running on AWS so I doubt there is a server problem.  The post data just doesn't seem to be sent in my implementation for some reason.

Comment: I have tested your implementation. and it is working. So it is no related to the code you have posted